# Unable to start Chrome Driver - Alpine Linux

Tags: java, linux, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, alpine-linux

i am setting up a selenium based testing application. I am using chrome driver for testing.

I have set up a docker image as in the below URL.

https://github.com/Leafney/alpine-selenium-chrome/blob/master/Dockerfile

I have configured the chrome driver property as follows.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/lib/chromium/chromedriver");
```

However, I get the below error informing that chrome failed to start.

Command duration or timeout: 60.07 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'c34db8dbfca2', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.27-moby', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed

Any pointers on this will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe try latest version first (Alpine v3.7), Alpine v3.4 is very old...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, I am finding the same problem with Alpine

Comment: Unfortunately no.. I had to procure a windows box to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with Chromedriver and Alpine, Chromedriver is not executable at all, even I had tried to install and run almost every version of the Chromedriver, no luck.
And then I had to use Debian Linux in order to execute Chromedriver properly for e2e testing in docker and CI.